# AC circuit analysis: Why does current have the same frequency as the voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, frequency

[image]

The above example we have a 50hz AC voltage source. Why is that when we solve for I, I must have frequency of 50 Hz?

Is there any physical (non-mathematical) reason to explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple reason is that you have only ***passive, linear, time-invariant*** components in your circuit; when you push with a certain voltage, you get a certain current response. If the voltage cycles a certain number of times per second, that's how often the current must respond.

Think about it the other way - if you _didn't_have the same frequency, what response would make sense?

Again - this is only true for passive, linear components. If you have an active circuit (for example, an oscillator) it can obviously have a different frequency response. And when you have a nonlinear circuit component, you will typically end up with harmonics of the driving frequency.

Now with a tiny bit of mathematics: every component in your circuit has a certain impedance $Z$. For resistors, that is $Z=R$ - the resistance in Ohms, which is constant with frequency.

For a capacitor, the impedance is

$$Z = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$

Again, we can say $V = I \cdot Z$ but note that while the response will have the same frequency, there will be a phase shift (and a dependence on frequency - when frequency is larger, impedance is smaller and current is larger).

Similarly, for an inductor we have impedance

$$Z = j\omega L$$

Once again, there is no nonlinearity, and the input and output have to have the same frequency.

There are many cyclical phenomena in nature - the sun comes up once a day, and once a day it gets hot (assuming there are no clouds, wind, etc). Think of the sun's cycle as the voltage (driving force) and the temperature of the air as the current (the response). Even though it might lag (it might be warmest later in the afternoon), you wouldn't expect the cycle of heat to be anything except daily (unless there were other factors present which would defeat the condition of linear, passive components).

Comment: This is true for a stationary situation but initially there are transient terms when the AC source is switched on.

Comment: @Urgje yes - but in that case there are in essence multiple driving frequencies (the Fourier transform of the step) . AC analysis is not the same thing as transient analysis but in either case no frequencies should appear on the current that are note present in the voltage.

Comment: @Urgje even in that case voltage and current have the same frequency, simply their amplitudes changes both sinusoidally _and exponentially_, but their phase shifts and frequency stay the same throughout the transient response

Comment: "The simple reason is that you have only passive, linear components in your circuit" // Actually, those are not sufficient conditions. Those components must also be time-invariant. If the circuit had linear time-variant components, then the current can have different frequency than the voltage.

Comment: @alejnavab thanks. Updated answer to reflect that refinement.